# Prism: InvalidOperationException at region deactivation. "Deactivation is not possible in this type of region."

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, prism-5

I'm developing an WPF application with PRISM 5.0.

At some point I want to deactivate all active views in specific region.

```
IRegion contentRegion = _regionManager.Regions
    .First(region => region.Name == RegionNames.ContentRegion);

foreach (object view in contentRegion.ActiveViews)
{
    contentRegion.Deactivate(view);
}
```

But at this point I get an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Deactivation is not possible in this type of region.
  Source=Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Composition
  StackTrace: ...
  InnerException:
```

---

My region is only declared at base view Shell.xaml as

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="#193441"  BorderThickness="2,2,2,2">
    <ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" />
</Border>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Region Deactivate depends on implementation

Behaviour of `Deactivate` on `IRegion` depends on it's implementation that you set declaring region in xaml.

Its implementation is set by type of control that is set at view (main view Shell.xaml here).

#### Possible implementations and how to set them:

- `SingleActiveRegion` (set by `ContentControl`): only one active region at a time. It automatycly deactivate views at other view activation.
- `AllActiveRegion` (set by `ItemsControl`): All views are visible and active. Calling `Deactivate` will cause `InvalidOperationException`.
- `Region` (set by `Selector`): It allows multiple active and deactive views.

It's widely described in [this post](http://southworks.com/blog/2009/07/02/how-to-hide-views-inside-composite-application-guidance-aka-prism-v2-regions/).

### Change region declaration

For me it is more comfortable to had only one active view in this region, so I've changed region declaration in `Shell.xaml` to:

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="#193441"  BorderThickness="2,2,2,2">
    <ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" />
</Border>
```

And now my region is type of `SingleActiveRegion` where I don't have to call `Deactivate`.

#### When can i use `Deactivate`

- When you have `ContentControl` and you want to deactivate only active view
- If you want to keep multiple active views you have to use `Selector` control in .xaml - then you can use `Deactivate`

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed answer. It helped me to understand better and resolve issues quickly. Thanks again.